# getting the max of each group in a MySql query

Tags: mysql

Whilst I realise this question has been asked in many forms before, sadly the threads that deal with this problem have no helped my situation.

I have a table that looks like this for example:

```
id|forename|surname|house|gen|academic|sense|dedicated|balance|respect
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |dav1    |jone1  |n    |1  |2       |3    |4        |5      |18
2 |dav2    |jone2  |s    |1  |2       |3    |4        |5      |9
3 |dav3    |jone3  |w    |1  |2       |3    |4        |5      |10
4 |dav4    |jone4  |w    |1  |2       |3    |4        |5      |11
5 |dav5    |jone5  |n    |1  |2       |3    |4        |5      |12
6 |dav6    |jone6  |h    |1  |2       |3    |4        |5      |13
7 |dav7    |jone7  |h    |1  |2       |3    |4        |5      |14
```

And the output I would like is:

```
id|forename|surname|house|total
-------------------------------
1 |dav1    |jone1  |n    |33  
4 |dav4    |jone4  |w    |26  
2 |dav2    |jone2  |s    |24  
7 |dav7    |jone7  |h    |29
```

So it gets the combined total of the six integer columns, then takes the highest from each of the houses and returns the total, the name, the house and the id.

I have done quite a few iterations, and it seems I need to do a nested table (I dont know the exact term for it), but this is what I have been working along the lines of:

```
SELECT utable.id, utable.forename, utable.surname, utable.house, (utable.gen+utable.academic+utable.sense+utable.dedicated+utable.balance+utable.respect) AS utable.points
FROM (
    SELECT house, max(`gen`+`academic`+`sense`+`dedicated`+`balance`+`respect`) AS pts FROM users             GROUP BY house
) AS ntable
INNER JOIN users AS utable ON utable.house = ntable.house AND utable.points = ntable.pts
```

However it isnt working, and in particular right now is says the utable.points has an alias that was previously found. I think it has something to do with how I am summing the columns to make the total points but im not sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

(while I know this will get flagged up as a repeat request, I have tried the other threads and a few websites to try and get this to work to no avail. I am testing it in phpMyAdmin server type is MariaDB 5.5.46-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.2 - (Ubuntu))

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there, basically you need a sub-query to get information like above:

```
SELECT u.id, u.forename, u.surname, u.house, max_u.pts
FROM users u, (
    SELECT house, max(gen+academic+sense+dedicated+balance+respect) pts 
    FROM users
    GROUP BY 1
) AS max_u
WHERE u.house = max_u.house 
and gen+academic+sense+dedicated+balance+respect = max_u.pts
```

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you - I never thought to put the sum in the WHERE part of the statement. Really appreciate it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing joins you can simplify it by ordering on the inner query and then grouping on the outer query:

```
select * from (select id, forename, surname, house, (gen + academic + sense + dedicated + balance + respect) as total from Table1 order by house, total desc) x group by house;
```

This is a bit of a trick because if you group in descending order by total it will automatically rank the max at the top of each house group. Then when you group by house it will take the max value for each house.

The only issue I can forsee that you might have to think about is what if two rows have are tied for the same maximum value?

Here's an SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25bd8e/14

The above is a MySQL solution without needing joins. If you are using PostgreSQL instead you can use this:

```
select distinct on (house) id, forename, surname, house, (gen + academic + sense + dedicated + balance + respect) as total from Table1 order by house, total desc;
```

Comment: @SIDU If you are going to claim my code is incorrect please provide a counter example of how my code will fail.

Comment: He wants the join with original row based on the max points - you can try to run your SQL and it will not work as expected.

Comment: Can you provide an example of values where my code will fail. The only situation where I can see an issue is with totals that tie for the max value.

Comment: You can simply use above data into your test table, and run your SQL, it will not produce the result as expected.

Comment: Actually if you look at my SQL Fiddle that I posted it uses the same data and gets the exact results that he wanted plus is a bit faster in execution time.

Comment: I see what you mean now. The SQL itself is not kind-of-valid, however MySQL works in this case. If you run this SQL in PostgreSQL, it should be syntax error

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I am not used to PostgreSQL.

Comment: I have also added a PostgreSQL alternative that seems to do the job, though SQL Fiddle was being a bit buggy so couldn't fully test it.

Comment: Hi kojow7, I have copied your codes from SQL Fiddle into my local postgres (v9.4) it shows exactly same error. I understand standard SQL requires you to include all columns names (except the aggregated) into the group by -- luckily or Brain-washingly by MySQL, such invalid SQL does not return an error

Comment: I think you tried the MySQL code option with your PostgreSQL. I also posted a valid PostgreSQL one that should work with your local install using "distinct on". However, I agree with what you are saying and did not realize MySQL and PostgreSQL do not follow the standards.